# Variables/example for sending a new member their login details using Postmaster

Tags: add-on, members, email, postmaster

I've just upgraded to Postmaster 1.2, and want to set it up to send emails to new users when their new member accounts are created (but not edited). I'm also using EE 2.5.3 and Profile:Edit 1.0.7.

I've created a new Hook using the Profile Register End hook, but what are the variables I'm meant to use for the following items?

- New member's username
- New member's password (as the client insists on sending this)
- New member's screen name (for use in the To Name field)
- New member's email address (for use in the To Email field)
- New member's custom fields (via Profile:Edit tags?)

Looking through the [Postmaster docs](https://objectivehtml.com/postmaster/hooks), I can see that the member variables are just for the logged-in user so are of no use for this. It'd be nice to have a full working example to go from as it feels a bit different to creating a standard parcel based on channel entries. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default the member variables use the logged in member, but the hooks API gives developers  the ability to override that, which Profile:edit does. Each hook inherits the same rules, but they can break them at will. I will try to improve documentation on special exceptions.

So when you register or edit a profile, the member data that gets passed to the template is relevant to the one you just created/edited.

```
{member:username}
{member:screen_name}
{member:email}
{hook:password} (Unencrypted password) 
{member:password} (Encrypted password)
{hook:your_custom_field}
{hook:entry_id} (Entry_id of the profile entry)
```

As far as the example goes, I am going to work on getting some video tutorials together soon. I spent a lot of time working on the docs, but it's impossible to get everything everyone needs from the start. I know I didn't cover everything. I definitely want to improve this, it just takes a lot of time.

EDIT:

**Be sure to update to Profile:edit v1.0.8. Anything prior to this release does not contain any hooks.**

Comment: Thanks for confirming those variables. I've just created a new Hook using the pre-installed profile_register_end hook. I've got ExpressionEngine as my email service (I know you don't like this, but it works fine for my other parcels), and the email should be going to this name: {member:screen_name} and this email: {member:email}. I've also BCC'd my gmail email. I created a new user on both the front end (using exp:profile:register tag) and in the back end CP, but I didn't receive any emails for either (I've checked spam folders too). Any ideas what's going wrong?

Comment: In the Profile:Edit module options, I've just tried changing the 'Send new member notifications' to Yes. I then created another user via the exp:profile:register tag. This time, I got the standard EE email notification of a new user to the admin email address, but still no email from Postmaster.

Comment: I **REALLY** need to get the email debugging/logging feature in place. This is getting impossible to diagnose why emails aren't getting sent at first. It's almost alway a parsing issue. Can you try to hardcode email in the to/from fields and use the message contents to test your variables? Output all the variables in the message that aren't parsing in the to/from fields and see which ones get parsed in the email. Hardcoding the emails will confirm the hook is getting sent. Also check the exp_extensions table with a SQL client and see if Profile:edit hooks are installed.

Comment: I tried hard-coding the email address and name, then created a new entry on the front end using the exp:profile:register tag, but still no email I'm afraid. Looking in the ext_extensions table and there's various Profile:Edit and Postmaster hooks so not sure which one(s) I need to check for. profile_register_end is there though.

Comment: Are you using Profile:edit v1.0.8? Anything prior to that won't work because the hooks aren't available.

Comment: The changelog on the Profile:Edit site only goes up to 1.0.7. Are you sure 1.0.8 is publicly available?

Comment: I assumed it was since I have a copy of it (I built these hooks on contract for another dev). Email support[at]objectivehtml.com if you can't find the public version of 1.0.8. I used the other dev's site files and license to build this, I don't personally use Profile:edit.

Comment: I've sent a message to Mighty Big Robot and will let you know how I get on (or don't get on!). Profile:Edit Downloads are currently broke on their site (I guess, after the recent site changes with CartThrob etc) and they've not been keeping upto date with forum posts either...