# Postmaster + Zoo Visitor + custom fields

Tags: zoo-visitor, postmaster

I'm using Zoo Visitor to register members and I've set up Postmaster to email based on a checkbox group (using extra conditionals in Postmaster).

Postmaster sends the email fine, but it uses Zoo Visitor's default email address instead of the one the user put in during registration. This is using a parcel, and the email code looks like this:

```
Hello! This new member is interested in joining the Marketing Committee. Here is their contact info:
<br><br>
<strong>Name:</strong> {parcel:member_firstname} {parcel:member_lastname}
<br>
<strong>Email:</strong> {member:email}
<br>
<strong>Phone:</strong> {parcel:member_phone}
```

`{member:email}` ends up getting parsed like so: `zoo_visitor@yourdomain.tld`

I read in a couple of threads over at Devot:ee that using the installed Zoo Visitor Hook in Postmaster would solve this. It does, but then I can't get the custom fields to output properly. The code for that is like so:

```
Hello! This new member is interested in joining the Marketing Committee. Here is their contact info:
<br><br>
<strong>Name:</strong> {member:member_firstname} {member_firstname}
<br>
<strong>Email:</strong> {member:email}
<br>
<strong>Phone:</strong> {member_phone}
```

`{member:email}` outputs properly, but the other tags don't, and I'm not sure what the proper syntax is for those.

I need to be able to output all the info in the Zoo Visitor channel entry.

Any ideas?

Comment: In my Zoo Visitor set-up I use email for the member title as its unique. I then use {parcel:title} in Postmaster to render the email. Dunno if you have similar?

Comment: I don't unfortunately (client prefers first/last names as title), but that would be a perfect solution. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angie,

You need the Zoo Visitor Register End Hook in Postmaster's settings.

Check this post a bit related [Variables/example for sending a new member their login details using Postmaster](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/1907/variables-example-for-sending-a-new-member-their-login-details-using-postmaster)

Comment: Hm, that returns nothing for me (have tried different options in the status parameter). That's on a parcel, not a hook, right?

Comment: I've marked this as the answer, but it really needs more info. Basically, in addition to using the Zoo Visitor Register End Hook in Postmaster (rather than a Parcel), the code syntax to get the custom fields to show is {hook:custom_field}.